# Cant run rails server, project is telling me i dont have node even though I do?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

So after executing the following commands:

1. `rails new sample_app`
2. `cd sample_app`
3. `rails db:create`
4. `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`
5. `rails db:migrate`

and finaly when i run `rails server` i get:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:103:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `data'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:47:in `bootstrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:581:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/config/webpacker.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:581:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:581:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:113:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:97:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `data'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:47:in `bootstrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

note: this is the output from rails new sample_app

```
$ rails new sample_app
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru    
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/rober/rubystuff/pokehuddle_ruby_on_rails_BE/sample_app/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/spring
      create  bin/yarn
      remove  bin/spring
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
      create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using activesupport 6.1.4
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.11.7 (x64-mingw32)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.11.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.1.4
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.1.4
Using nio4r 2.5.7
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using actioncable 6.1.4
Using globalid 0.5.1
Using activejob 6.1.4
Using activemodel 6.1.4
Using activerecord 6.1.4
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using mini_mime 1.1.0
Using activestorage 6.1.4
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.4
Using actionmailer 6.1.4
Using actiontext 6.1.4
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using bootsnap 1.7.6
Using bundler 2.2.22
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 2.1.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.35.3
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.15.3 (x64-mingw32)
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using puma 5.4.0
Using rack-mini-profiler 2.3.2
Using rack-proxy 0.7.0
Using thor 1.1.0
Using railties 6.1.4
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 6.1.4
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using sassc 2.4.0 (x64-mingw32)
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using semantic_range 3.0.0
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using tzinfo-data 1.2021.1
Using web-console 4.1.0
Using webdrivers 4.6.0
Using webpacker 5.4.0
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 70 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  webpacker:install
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Exiting!
```

Ive tried the suggested rails webpacker:install command and it gave me this

```
$ rails webpacker:install
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Exiting!
```

ive checked my enviornment variables for node and its there on both the user:

[image]

and the system level:

[image]

ive also tried :

```
$ gem install node
Fetching node_int-0.1.3.gem
Fetching node_impl-1.0.0.gem
Fetching node-2.1.0.gem
Successfully installed node_int-0.1.3
Successfully installed node_impl-1.0.0
Successfully installed node-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for node_int-0.1.3
Installing ri documentation for node_int-0.1.3
Parsing documentation for node_impl-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for node_impl-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for node-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for node-2.1.0
Done installing documentation for node_int, node_impl, node after 1 seconds
3 gems installed
```

and

```
$ yarn add node
yarn add v1.22.5
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ node@16.6.0
info All dependencies
└─ node@16.6.0
Done in 3.58s.
```

just incase but they both didnt effect the outcome of the rails server, i still got the same error message.

I've checked my yarn and node versions:

```
$ node -v
v14.16.0
```

```
$ yarn -v
1.22.5
```

Im new to ruby on rails and I have a Windows 10 OS and I know that its more difficult to run ruby but that is my situation right now unfortunately. I also am not as familiar with yarn as im used to npm. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you should add node or/and node.js to your PATH. At your place I'd try locating node/node.js binary, and push them at the end of the PATH variable.
Also, have you considered using WSL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `webpacker.yml` file in your apps `config` file. I also suggest running `bundle install` and `bundle update` commands before launching the rails server after you installed a gem. Here's a closed issue similar to your problem; https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/940

Comment: Thank you! this actually worked! it seems like rails was looking for webpacker.yml before it was bootstraped.